# render as JSON clipping of the zeros of the floating point value

Tags: json, grails

I have a map which is like this, which has to be rendered as JSON to the output.

```
def formatedResult =  [ 
    results:[
        [ Name:foo, sex:m, salary:171.900 ], 
        [ Name:bar, sex:m, salary:171.900 ]
    ]
]
```

I am rendering this response as

```
withFormat {
    json {
        render formatedResult as JSON
    }
}
```

which produces the following result.

```
{
    results: [{
        Name: "foo",
        sex: "m",
        salary: 171.9
    }, {
        Name: "bar",
        sex: "m",
        salary: 171.9
    }]
}
```

But is clipping off the zeros from the salary. What should I do to get the JSON with out clipping off the zeros?

Comment: That's the same number. If you're bothered about the string representation, convert the numbers to strings

Answer (score 0):

If you are hard coding your values as in your example put them like this:

```
def formatedResult =  [ 
    results:[
        [ Name:foo, sex:m, salary:"171.900" ], 
        [ Name:bar, sex:m, salary:"171.900" ]
    ]
]
```

Or if you are getting them from variable use `toString()` method to convert them to string.

```
def formatedResult =  [ 
    results:[
        [ Name:foo, sex:m, salary:salary.toString()], 
        [ Name:bar, sex:m, salary:salary.toString()]
    ]
]
```

Finally your render:

```
withFormat {
    json {
        render formatedResult as JSON
    }
}
```